# /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: This program requires a machine with at least 2000 megabytes of memory

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: This program requires a machine with at least 2000 megabytes of memory

Hi there, I am deploying .NET Core, Angular, MS SQL to EC2 (Ubuntu). But I got this error "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: This program requires a machine with at least 2000 megabytes of memory.". Any one met this, Can you help, please!. Thank you so much!.

[mssql image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFX6x.png)

[Ubuntu version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E8uU.png)

**docker-compose file:**

```
version: "3"
services:
    ui-service:
        container_name: adamstoreclient
        image: registry.gitlab.com/lehoa08121998/adamstoreclient/main:latest
        ports: 
          - "80:80"
        networks:
          - adamstore
    dotnet-app:
        container_name: dotnet-core5.0
        image: registry.gitlab.com/lehoa08121998/adamstore/main:latest
        ports:
            - '5000:5000'
        depends_on:
            - ms-sqlserver
        entrypoint: dotnet API.dll
        networks:
          - adamstore
    ms-sqlserver:
        container_name: ms-sqldb
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
        environment:
          ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
          SA_PASSWORD: "Secret123!@#"
          MSSQL_PID: Express
        ports:
           - "1433:1433"
        volumes: 
          - sqlsystem:/var/opt/mssql/
          - sqldata:/var/opt/sqlserver/data
          - sqllog:/var/opt/sqlserver/log
          - sqlbackup:/var/opt/sqlserver/backup
        networks:
          - adamstore
volumes:
    sqlsystem:
    sqldata:
    sqllog:
    sqlbackup:
networks:
    adamstore:
```

Comment: Memory and storage are 2 different things... Having 9.7GB free **storage** doesn't mean you meet the minimal specs required for memory.

Comment: @Larnu, Co can you give me a way to resolve that? Thanks.

Comment: You *need* more memory; it's as simple as that.

Comment: Do you mind if you give me a walkthrough or key word to search it?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/114

Answer (score 1):

At the command prompt issue `free -h` and make sure the `free` column has at least 2GB available **before** you start the sqlserver container.